# I'm getting an error whe I use json file firebase SDK in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, firebase, firebase-authentication

I adding the firebase json file to use [firebase_admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) with django.

the code I'm using in Django is:

```
import os
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import auth

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
cred = credentials.RefreshToken(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'firebase-sdk.json'))
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
```

and the error I get is:

```
  File "/home/eavinti/Documentos/AGMATIS/venv-entrely/entrely/apps/legacy/management/commands/import_auth.py", line 17, in <module>
    cred = credentials.RefreshToken(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'firebase-sdk.json'))
  File "/home/eavinti/Documentos/AGMATIS/venv-entrely/lib/python3.8/site-packages/firebase_admin/credentials.py", line 193, in __init__
    raise ValueError('Invalid refresh token configuration. JSON must contain a '
ValueError: Invalid refresh token configuration. JSON must contain a "type" field set to "authorized_user".
```

I just run it without django  and works perfectly:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials

cred = credentials.Certificate("firebase-sdk.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in django.

Answer (score 2):

I already figured out

I just had to create a  environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`

and initialize firebase with

```
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app()
```

Comment: I don't get why environment variable working and json credential file path not working... They should be both working as guided [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk). Is it a bug of firebase_admin?

> When authorizing via a service account, you have two choices for providing the credentials to your application. You can either set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable, or you can explicitly pass the path to the service account key in code.

Comment: I agree making envvar GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS working!

Answer (score 2):

To prevent this error, use

```
credentials.Certificate("path/to/token.json")
```

instead of

```
 credentials.RefreshToken(...)
```